# Steering wheel controller for PS3

Tags: ps3, controllers

I am thinking about getting a steering wheel controller for the PS3, primarily for Gran Turismo 5.

Is there a website which compares all the available options, so I can choose the best one for me?

Comment: Upvote for not asking a subjective question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks be exactly what you are looking for: [PS3 Steering Wheel comparison guide](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/69211-ps3-steering-wheel-comparison-guide.html).

It also compares them across rough price ranges so you can also use it to find the best for your budget rather than just an overly expensive one that is the best overall.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was after.